# Filtering HTTPS traffic?

Tags: http, https, tcp, filtering

Is it possible to filter HTTPs traffic?

For example via a TDI filter? Or perhaps you need to use a proxy?

[This product](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) seems to do filtering of HTTPS traffic and I'd like to know how it does it, as well as if this is the only way.

How about via the [Windows Filtering Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/network/wfp.mspx) for Vista and up?

Comment: I don't see that this is particularly programming-related ... Can you rephrase your question, perhaps? Are you looking for a product or wondering how to write your own https-proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler is simply a proxy; it decrypts HTTPS traffic using a Man-in-the-Middle approach. See https://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp for more information on this.

With WFP/TDI, you could only see if the the target endpoint (IP+PORT) matches some combination when deciding whether to allow or deny the traffic. If you want to interfere with the traffic itself, you must either be a proxy (see http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) or you need to inject yourself into the pre/post decyrption HTTPS traffic using either an APP-wrapper (not recommended) or a DETOURs like approach.

Answer (score 1):

The traffic flowing inside an HTTPS session is opaque to all but the end-points: so, if you require filtering of the said traffic you must either:

1. act as one of the end-points
2. sit behind an end-point

In both cases, you could implement this functionality through a "proxy" thereby requiring the "real end-points" to forward their traffic through the said proxy function.

Of course, this pretty much depends but what you mean by "filtering" :-)